# How to judge whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ converges

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Given $u_{n}=(-1)^{n} \ln \left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$, I want to judge the convergence of series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}$ and series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}^{2}$.

```
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> "RootTest"]
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> "RaabeTest"]
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> "IntegralTest"]
```

But the above four methods can not judge whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}$ converges or not.

What method should I use to quickly judge whether the above series converges?

*The answer is that series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}$ converges and series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_{n}^{2}$ diverges.*

Comment: `SumConvergence[…,Method->Automatic]` works in both cases!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Even if I set the option to `Method->Automatic`, I still can't get the correct result:`SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> Automatic]`.

Comment: Which Mathematica version?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann V12.1.1 on Win10.

Comment: To look at each method you might find this template useful: `{#, SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> #]} & /@ {Automatic, "RatioTest", "RootTest", "RaabeTest", "IntegralTest"} // Grid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SumConvergence` works on Mathematica v12 Windows 10:

```
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n, Method -> Automatic]
(*True*)
SumConvergence[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], n ]
(*True*)
NSum[(-1)^n Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]], {n, 1, Infinity}]
(*-0.401098*)

SumConvergence[  Log[1 + 1/Sqrt[n]]^2, n, Method -> Automatic]
(*False *)
```